# Error build cordova visual studio

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using visual studio cordova tools and i changed the version from 4.3 to 6.0
But now i'm receiving this error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>  * What went wrong:
1>  Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
1>  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:       org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 1>
 1>
 1>  * Try:
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
 1>  BUILD FAILED
  1>
  1>  Total time: 3.53 secs
  1>  ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Onsen_UI_app\app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\me\Desktop\Onsen_UI_app\app\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
 1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
  1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Onsen_UI_app\app\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\me\Desktop\Onsen_UI_app\app\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
 ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
 ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```